# Github webhook error: We couldn’t deliver this payload: No error

Tags: github, webhooks

I can trigger the jenkins job from terminal using `curl` command:

```
    curl -X POST http://jenkins:USER_ID@MY_Jenkins_server_public_IP:8080/job/JOBNAME/build?token=MyTocken
```

But when I try to do it from Github they can`t deliver the message.

I can access and login to MY_Jenkins_server_public_IP:8080 from my computer and mobile phone.

How do I trigger jenkins jobs from github?

Comment: Does your phone connected to the internal organizational WiFi?

Comment: No, Wifi is off on my phone. Jenkins is reachable on public IP